# How to specify alternative json path for a element that might have two different types

Tags: jsonpath

Consider following situation for `call` field in phoneNumbers array, it can have object or string as a value.

Basically I want to be able to say **either get me `Prefix` value OR whatever string value there is in field `call`**

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888",
      "call": {"Prefix": 23}
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910",
      "call": "NA"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way using which can I can provide secondary path for a field?